# Filter out rows depending on action that could be performed in different HTML pages

Tags: pandas

We record user interaction on a website with the naming convention **action_cardType**. We have 8 cardType values. For example:

- `view_detail_<xxx>` (e.g. *view_detail_role*, *view_detail_mentor*...)
- `explore_more_<xxx>` (e.g. explore_more_learning)

piece of sample data:

```
module,page,step1,step2,step3
goal,goalLanding,view_page,view_detail_assignment,ExitPage
goal,goalLanding,view_page,view_detail_role,explore_more
goal,goalLanding,view_page,view_detail_mentor,ExitPage
goal,goalLanding,view_page,view_detail_mentoringProgram,view_card_detail
goal,goalLanding,view_page,explore_more_assignment,ExitPage
goal,goalLanding,view_page,explore_more_learning,view_manage_opportunities
goal,goalLanding,view_page,explore_more_connectWithPeople,bookmark
goal,goalLanding,view_page,back_to_opp,view_snack
goal,goalLanding,view_page,join_as_mentee,view_snack
goal,goalLanding,view_page,ExitPage
```

**Goal**
I want to filter out the rows for which step2 action couldn't be performed in goalLanding page.

**What I have tried**:
I pre-defined all the actions that exist on goalLanding page in a list regex expression list.

```
List = [r'explore_now(\S+)', r'view_detail(\S+)', 'ExitPage']
```

then I tried to use this script to filter out invalid rows:

```
df = df.loc[df['step2'].isin(List)]
```

The expected result after cleaning should be:

```
module,page,step1,step2,step3
goal,goalLanding,view_page,view_detail_assignment,ExitPage
goal,goalLanding,view_page,view_detail_role,explore_more
goal,goalLanding,view_page,view_detail_mentor,ExitPage
goal,goalLanding,view_page,view_detail_mentoringProgram,view_card_detail
goal,goalLanding,view_page,explore_more_assignment,ExitPage
goal,goalLanding,view_page,explore_more_learning,view_manage_opportunities
goal,goalLanding,view_page,explore_more_connectWithPeople,bookmark
goal,goalLanding,view_page,ExitPage
```

But the above approach doesn't work.

Can anyone help? As the data to be cleaned is huge, is there any convenient and straightforward way to achieve this?

Thanks,
Cherie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use isin to match several regexes; what you **CAN** do however, is compute a mask that combine several regex matches, and use it to filter out your rows.

Assuming you have df as follow

```
>>> df
  module         page      step1                           step2                      step3
0   goal  goalLanding  view_page          view_detail_assignment                   ExitPage
1   goal  goalLanding  view_page                view_detail_role               explore_more
2   goal  goalLanding  view_page              view_detail_mentor                   ExitPage
3   goal  goalLanding  view_page    view_detail_mentoringProgram           view_card_detail
4   goal  goalLanding  view_page         explore_more_assignment                   ExitPage
5   goal  goalLanding  view_page           explore_more_learning  view_manage_opportunities
6   goal  goalLanding  view_page  explore_more_connectWithPeople                   bookmark
7   goal  goalLanding  view_page                     back_to_opp                 view_snack
8   goal  goalLanding  view_page                  join_as_mentee                 view_snack
9   goal  goalLanding  view_page                        ExitPage                        NaN
```

You can easily get which row match *view_detail* (or anything really) with the following

```
>>> mask1 = df.step2.str.match(r"view_detail(\S+)")
>>> mask2 = df.step2.str.match(r"explore_more_(\S+)")
>>> mask3 = df.step2.str.match(r"ExitPage")
>>> mask1
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
Name: step2, dtype: bool
```

Alternatively, if you're just concerned with the start of the string, you can use

```
mask1 = df.step2.str.startswith("view_detail")
...
```

Then, just combine these masks with a logical OR and Voilà!

```
>>> df = df[mask1|mask2|mask3]
>>> df
  module         page      step1                           step2                      step3
0   goal  goalLanding  view_page          view_detail_assignment                   ExitPage
1   goal  goalLanding  view_page                view_detail_role               explore_more
2   goal  goalLanding  view_page              view_detail_mentor                   ExitPage
3   goal  goalLanding  view_page    view_detail_mentoringProgram           view_card_detail
4   goal  goalLanding  view_page         explore_more_assignment                   ExitPage
5   goal  goalLanding  view_page           explore_more_learning  view_manage_opportunities
6   goal  goalLanding  view_page  explore_more_connectWithPeople                   bookmark
9   goal  goalLanding  view_page                        ExitPage                        NaN
```

**Note**
It is a bit unwieldy to define these masks manualy. You can use a list comprehension and numpy's `reduce` function to automate the process

```
import numpy as np

regexes = [r"view_detail(\S+)", r"explore_more_(\S+)", r"ExitPage"]
mask = np.logical_or.reduce([df.step2.str.match(regex) for regex in regexes])
df = df[mask]
```